# Javascript line number mapping

Tags: javascript

Magically formatted comments will change the reported line number of javascript errors in some browsers; They look like this:

```
//@line n "f"
```

`n` is the line number and `f` is the file name. Unfortunately, `//@line` appears to be ungoogleable. Does anyone know where there is documentation on this feature, and which browsers support it?

(I found references to it [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=618650) and [here](http://intertwingly.net/blog/2010/11/25/Hobgoblin-of-Little-Minds#c1292142367).)

Comment: I guess this feature is Firefox only. Brendan Eich is father of Javascript and he is chief technology officer at the Mozilla Corporation. From one of your links I can assume that this is a hack, so doubt this feature is documented anywhere.

Comment: I thought I remembered seeing that safari supported it too, but I can't find that anywhere...

Comment: apparently, `//@line` only works for scripts with chrome permissions (extensions, and firefox itself,) and is not available for javascript on web pages.

Comment: I was confusing this with `@Sourceurl`, supported in firebug (http://blog.getfirebug.com/2009/08/11/give-your-eval-a-name-with-sourceurl/) and webkit (http://pmuellr.blogspot.com/2009/06/debugger-friendly.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can find it is only available in Mozilla based browsers.

It is using the JS_SetOptions command which can turn these options on or off depending on the values passed.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JS_SetOptions