# Analog of #line 123 for JavaScript console

Tags: javascript, php, debugging

My HTML files are generated from PHP code. In the error messages, the debug console on Chrome reports the line number in the generated file, not in the original PHP file. Is there an easy way to see the line number in my PHP file instead?

In C, this is done with the `#line` pragma:

```
#line 123
if (x = 0) // oops
     x = 1;
```

here the warning will indicate a problem on line 124 (presumably of the program that generated this code), not on line 2.

Is there a simple way to do this in JavaScript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript line number mapping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584443/javascript-line-number-mapping)

Comment: @NathanTuggy Probably. Perhaps you can make it an answer.